# Comparison of the solubility of lead(II) iodide in water and in lead(II) nitrate solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, solubility

> Solubility of $\ce{PbI2}$: Is $\ce{PbI2}$ more soluble in $\ce{H2O}$ or in an aqueous solution of Lead(II) nitrate?
> $K_\mathrm{sp} (\ce{PbI_{2}})=8.7\times 10^{-9}$

I'm not very good in Chemistry, I study mathematics and now I have this exam (in chemistry), but I have no idea how to proceed in this exercise. Can someone explain the method to solve it?

Comment: You have a chemistry exam. This doesn't look like math.

Comment: @Karl whay is the problem?

Comment: I asked help because I don't understand how to proceed with these exercises. I posted it in the forum of Chemistry so what means "This doesn't look like math" ?

Comment: If you are supposed to be able to answer this, then you *must* know a bit more. You're welcome to ask here if you encounter a problem when revising your lecture notes, but you must show your own effort.

Comment: Did you ever heard of common ion effect?

Comment: @Mathew Mahindaratne yes, and I know that PbI_{2} is not soluble in water. I wrot the dissociation reaction of PbI2 but I think that there aren't common ions with Lead(II) nitrate. Am I wrong?

Comment: Remember, $\ce{PbI2}$ is only sparingly soluble, thus cannot completely dissociate in water.  $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$, on the other hand very soluble and hence, completely dissociated in water. Therefore, you have $\ce{Pb^2+}$ present in that solution as a common ion.

Comment: **HINT** - Start at the beginning. Write out the chemical equations for lead iodide and lead nitrate dissolving in water. Then think about the [common ion effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-ion_effect) which is a specific case of [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In water the following equilibrium would establish:

$$\ce{PbI2 (s) <=> Pb^2+ (aq) + 2I- (aq) \tag1}$$

$$\therefore \ K_\mathrm{sp} = [\ce{Pb^2+}][\ce{I-}]^2 = 8.7 \times 10^{−9} \tag2$$

Now, using equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, you can calculate $[\ce{Pb^2+}]$ and $[\ce{I-}]$ in water.

In  $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution, following ions are present:

$$\ce{Pb(NO3)2 (aq) -> Pb^2+ (aq) + 2NO3- (aq) \tag3}$$

Thus, $\ce{Pb^2+}$ is present abundantly in the solution as the common ion (suppose $[\ce{Pb^2+}]$ is $\pu{0.1 M}$). Still, the equilibrium representing the equation $(1)$ should establish regardless of the presence of common ion. However, the equilibrium concentrations of $[\ce{Pb^2+}]$ and $[\ce{I-}]$ are very different than that of with pure water you calculated before. Yet, $K_\mathrm{sp}$ is still the same. So, you can again calculate $[\ce{I-}]$ using the equation $(2)$ and known $K_\mathrm{sp}$. Here, $[\ce{Pb^2+}] \approx \pu{0.1 M}$. You should think about the reson why we are using $[\ce{Pb^2+}] = \pu{0.1 M}$ here.

Once you find $[\ce{I-}]$ in water and in $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution, respectively, you would be able to see which solution makes $\ce{PbI2}$ more soluble.

Comment: If i didn't do it wrong, I think that PbI_{2} is more soluble in water. Am I right?

Comment: Excellent! Keep up with your work. Chemistry is not that bad. :-)